# AngularJS track global variable change in a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, global-variables, watch

I am using Angular v1.3.13.

I need to watch a global variable in order to enable/disable certain buttons in the template view.  I know the global variable is changing based on console.log output but its not updating in the controller...or I am not watching it properly.

While in this controller I need to initiate the $watch and keep watching while the user stays in this view/controller.

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function () {
    var gpsTracker = this;
    gpsTracker.gpsEnabled = mapInfo.gpsEnabled;
    $scope.$watch(angular.bind(this, function (gpsEnabled) {
        return this.gpsEnabled;
    }, function () {
        getLocationAuth()
    }));
});
```

I have tried several iterations but nothing has worked.  The object variable `mapInfo.gpsEnabled` is what I am try to track.

Comment: Have you tried: `$scope.$watch(() => gpsTracker.gpsEnabled, getLocationAuth);`?

Comment: @MichaelLynch - I changed my code to your recommendation and it did not work.  I feel my code is close but I am off just a bit.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with all that insane code manipulating the `this` object?

Comment: As mentioned, I went through many iterations pulling from different users solutions...none of them worked for me.  But I found another solution and it works 10 times cleaner than ingesting a $watch cycle.